# How do you select the whole table in postgres using golang sql?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm fairly new to posgres and Go, but have been struggling for a while on this. I'm currently trying to send a query to retrieve everything from a table.
When I try to use

```
SELECT * FROM land_registry_price_paid_uk
```

within postgres, it shows everything, but when I do the same using Query, I get.

```
sql: expected 16  destination arguments in Scan, not 1
```

This is the current code that I have.

```
fmt.Printf("user: %s, password: %s, dbName: %s", user, password, dbName)
connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s", user, password, dbName, "disable")
var err error
a.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
rows, err := a.DB.Query("SELECT ( * ) FROM land_registry_price_paid_uk")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
println(rows)
for rows.Next() {
    var name string
    if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("this is something: %s\n", name)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot scan 16 columns into a single `name` string. You need to pass 16 pointer arguments to the `Scan` call. If you're interested only in the `name` instead of `SELECT * ...` do `SELECT name ...` or whatever the name of the column you want is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your query is working just fine, you are returning 16 columns of data and trying to scan them all into a single string variable, you will need to provide a holder variable for each column:

```
var name string
// vars to hold other column values go here

// then reference vars in table order as args to row.Scan below
if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

if you have not used sql/go before you may also want to look into the special types provided for coping with nullable values as you will likely need these as well:

[NullString example](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString)

**Update:**

To further illustrate, say you had a three column table which consisted of the following fields:

- id (int)
- name (string)
- optional_data (string, nullable)

You might read the row as follows (not tested):

```
var (
    id int 
    name string
    optionalData sql.NullString
)

if err := rows.Scan(&id, &name, &optionalData); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you explain how do go about implementing a holder variable for each column?

Comment: Updated with an example

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot it was useful for me. but I would like to add a little bit more of information.
well I don't know what is your goalng's version but I'm using version  1.11.2 on windows/386 but when I added the parentheses this not worked. but without them it run perfect.

use this:
            rows, err := a.DB.Query("SELECT * FROM mytable")
instead of :
            rows, err := a.DB.Query("SELECT ( * ) FROM mytable")

and here is my example:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM words")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    println(rows)
    for rows.Next() {
        var word, exa1, exa2, mean string
        var id int
        if err := rows.Scan(&id, &word, &exa1, &exa2, &mean); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("id: %d\n word: %s \n example1: %s \n example2: %s \n meaning: %s\n---\n\n", id, word, exa1, exa2, mean)
    } 

  I hope this will be useful.
```